# Why is there more land-mass in The Northern Hemisphere?

Tags: earth, geophysics

So, this has been bugging my since my youth. When looking at a map of The Earth.

In the Southern Hemisphere, both Africa and South America are tall and slim, they get thinner towards the pole. Then there's Australia, and a huge amount of scattered smaller islands.

The Northern Hemisphere appears to have a huge amount of additional land-mass. Eurasia and North America are both tall and wide, they get thinner to the East and West.

What's the current understanding of this? There definitely seems to be a north-south divide in how the land is distributed.

Comment: Just a coincidence perhaps?

Comment: In addition to the other answers, Eurasia and North America aren't actually that tall/wide. The huge size of Canada, Greenland, and Russia are due to Mercator projection.

Comment: @knzhou yep. But still southern hemisphere contains only a third of the land

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics. [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) would be more suitable. In fact, it [already has an answer there](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4822/).

Comment: The Earth Science SE question suggests (among others) the rotational precession as a cause. This is something which physics can address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continents are constaly moving and how much landmass was in the northern hemisphere compared to the southern hemisphere (just as in the eastern hemisphere compared to the western hemisphere) was constantly changing.

For example in the devonian period most of the landmass was concentrated in the southern hemisphere.

[image: Devonian map]
[Source fot the paleomap](http://www.scotese.com/newpage3.htm)

So there is no reason. It's just a temporary situation

Comment: That's even more interesting, in that it suggests the continents overwhelmingly drifted north. I could see an argument based on the centrifugal force, that they might tend towards the equator, but past it?

Comment: @AJFaraday And before that they overwhelmingly drifted south. What you derive from that?

Comment: @AJFaraday As I understand while Earth rotation influence the process the main driving force for plate tectonics is assumed to be mantle convection processes that obviously involve much more parameters than lattitude. By the way I suggest you to look at this animation https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Continental_Drift_(740_million-to-Today).gif